# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token W - parseJSON error

Tags: php, jquery, sql, json, file-upload

So my problem is that I am trying to have this IF statement run once the file is confirmed transfered and uploaded. The only problem is that only 1 of these actions run. I have a loading bar that is supposed to reach 100% when the upload is finished. I get this in my browser: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token W - jquery-1.6.3.min.js:2
e.extend.parseJSON jquery-1.6.3.min.js:2
xhr.onload** .. however, if I use

```
INSERT INTO
```

before

`exit_status('File was uploaded successfuly!');`

The progressbar simply does not appear to run to 100%. However, if I put it first, it does reach 100%, but I do not insert anything into my SQL table. How can I fix this? and what is my mistake here?

```
 <?php
    // If you want to ignore the uploaded files,
    // set $demo_mode to true;

    $demo_mode = false;
    $upload_dir = '../img/gallery/';
    $allowed_ext = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');


    if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != 'post'){
        exit_status('Error! Wrong HTTP method!');
    }


    if(array_key_exists('pic',$_FILES) && $_FILES['pic']['error'] == 0 ){

        $pic = $_FILES['pic'];

        if(!in_array(get_extension($pic['name']),$allowed_ext)){
            exit_status('Only '.implode(',',$allowed_ext).' files are allowed!');
        }

        if($demo_mode){

            // File uploads are ignored. We only log them.

            $line = implode('       ', array( date('r'), $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $pic['size'], $pic['name']));
            file_put_contents('log.txt', $line.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

            exit_status('Uploads are ignored in demo mode.');
        }


        // Move the uploaded file from the temporary
        // directory to the uploads folder:
        $db = new PDO('mysql:DB INFO);
        $menuitemcount = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM bilder");
        $menuitemcount->execute();
        $menucount = $menuitemcount->rowCount();

        $newpicturename = $menucount.$pic['name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.$newpicturename)){
             date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo');
             $namepic = $pic['name'];
             $urlpic = "../img/gallery/".strval($menucount).$pic['name'];
             $altpic = $pic['name'];
             $datepic = date(Y,m,d);

             $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO bilder (name,url,alt,date) VALUES                (:name,:url,:alt,:date)");
             $query->execute(array(':name' => $namepic, ':url' => $urlpic, ':alt' => $altpic, ':date' => $datepic));
             exit_status('File was uploaded successfuly!');

        }
    }

    exit_status('Something went wrong with your upload!');



    // Helper functions

    function exit_status($str){
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>$str));
        exit;
    }

    function get_extension($file_name){
        $ext = explode('.', $file_name);
        $ext = array_pop($ext);
        return strtolower($ext);
    }
?>
```

**This is what I see when the INSERT operation on top:**
[image: SQL working, fileupload working but load bar is not 100%]

**This is when I change the spot for the insert operation and the exit_status:**
[image: 100% LOAD but SQL and UPLOAD not working]

**FULL SCRIPTS:**

http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/assets/js/script.js
http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/assets/js/jquery.filedrop.js

**POSSIBLY CAUSING THE ERROR:**

```
xhr.onload = function() { 
                if (xhr.responseText) {
                var now = new Date().getTime(),
                    timeDiff = now - start_time,
                    result = opts.uploadFinished(index, file, jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText), timeDiff);
                    filesDone++;
                    if (filesDone == files_count - filesRejected) {
                        afterAll();
                    }
                if (result === false) stop_loop = true;
```

Comment: It might be relevant what `exit_status()` does.

Comment: Well exit_status() is the one making it go to a 100%, but why doesn't exit_status() load after the INSERT operation is completed?

Comment: Turn on PHP error reporting, look at the error logs of your web server. I assume you use an AJAX call for the upload, so posting the relevant JavaScript might help. You could also try running the upload directly in the browser, without ajax so you can directly see any error messages (assuming you turned error reporting on, which is often disabled by default nowadays).

Comment: I think my problem was this: result = opts.uploadFinished(index, file, jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText), timeDiff);

Comment: Also added the relevant scripts :)

Answer (score 0):

You might have a syntax error in your SQL query because `date` is a reserved keyword. You should always enclose your table and column names with backticks.

```
INSERT INTO bilder (`name`,`url`,`alt`,`date`) VALUES (:name,:url,:alt,:date)
```

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sidenote: [`date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) is not a reserved word. *"You might have a syntax error in your SQL query because date is a reserved keyword"*